# PHP 7.1: Get file path from namespace

Tags: php, php-7.1

I have a project. I need to get the contents of a file in a package. I could do it the hard way:

```
file_get_contents('../../vendor/{vendor}/{package}/src/
    {directory}/{sub-directory}/class.php');
```

Or, I could do it the "easy way," which I'm pretty sure is impossible.

```
namespace MyVendor\MyProject;

use TheirVendor\TheirPackage\TheirClass;

class MyObject
{
    public function myFunction()
    {
        return file_get_contents(TheirClass);
    }
}
```

Is this (or something like it) possible?

Comment: so... `Vendor\Package\Class` => `Vendor/Package/Class.php`?

Comment: there's a psr that describe this

Comment: file path of what exactly? Dont fully understand

Comment: @Federkun's got the technical answer, but I'm wondering **why** you want to do this. Sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback everyone. I have completely rephrased the questions based on that feedback. @ceejayoz, I do apologize if it sounded like an XY problem, it was merely meant to be an example. Thank you again for the feedback.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get the file name of where a class is declared using a [`ReflectionClass` instance and its `getFileName()` method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getfilename.php):

```
$reflector = new ReflectionClass(\Vendor\Package\Class::class);
echo $reflector->getFileName();
```

Comment: Ooooh, elegant.

Comment: @ceejayoz PHP's reflection suite may be one of its saving graces.

Comment: Well done @Marty. You're awesome. Did recommend a little to match the rewrite of the question presented. I always forget about ReflectionClass and what it can do.

Comment: Thanks @JoshBruce, I did see that edit however from the perspective of someone coming across this thread reading the title and then quickly navigating to the accepted answer I thought it might overcomplicate things :-)

Comment: Looks like I didn't make "Link" into "TheirClass". Whoops.

Comment: @Marty fair enough. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `__NAMESPACE__` global and then replace the backslash with the proper directory separator, then use the `__FILE__` global to append the filename

```
$ns = str_replace( __NAMESPACE__, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '\\' );
$path = $ns.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.__FILE__;
```

and then do what you want with it.